# Daily Hurst Exponent

Tags: python

I am trying to estimate daily Hurst exponent values of a stock returns (e.g. for each day to have also Hurst exponent - something like that: https://www.quandl.com/data/PE/CKEC_HURST-Hurst-Exponent-of-Carmike-Cinemas-Inc-Common-Stock-CKEC-NASDAQ).

I am using this Python code (taken from https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Basics-of-Statistical-Mean-Reversion-Testing), but I do not know how to accommodate it for daily Hurst values instead of just one value:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from numpy import cumsum, log, polyfit, sqrt, std, subtract
from numpy.random import randn

def hurst(ts):

    """Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts"""
    # Create the range of lag values
    lags = range(2, 100)

    # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

    # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

    # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output
    return poly[0]*2.0


# Download the stock prices series from Yahoo
aapl = DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", datetime(2012,1,1), datetime(2015,9,18))

# Call the function
hurst(aapl['Adj Close'])
```

Comment: What is your question?  What should the code do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean:

```
from datetime import timedelta
current_date = datetime(2012,1,3)
end_date = datetime(2015,9,18)
aapl = DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", current_date, end_date)
index = 0
while index < len(aapl['Adj Close']):     
    print current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print hurst(aapl['Adj Close'][index:index + 1])
    index += 1
    current_date += timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I think in the code you wrote in the line  "aapl = DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", current_date, current_date)" you mean  "aapl = DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", current_date, end_date)".

Comment: No - the code as given calculates the daily version.  If you change it to what you have written then the exponent is not daily.  Also you will be retrieving the same data many times.

Comment: @Marcus I think you may try another method to get data from web only once, which is in my answer now.

Comment: @Marcus can you post the traceback?

Comment: 2012-01-01 00:00:00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7b7be73851f3> in <module>()
      4 while current_date <= end_date:
      5     print current_date
----> 6     print hurst(aapl['Adj Close'][current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")])
      7     current_date += timedelta(days=1)

C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    482     def __getitem__(self, key):
    483         try:

Comment: --> 484             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    485 
    486             if not np.isscalar(result):

C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   1256                 return self.get_value_maybe_box(series, key)
   1257             except (TypeError, ValueError, KeyError):
-> 1258                 raise KeyError(key)
   1259 
   1260     def get_value_maybe_box(self, series, key):

KeyError: '2012-01-01'

Comment: @YCFlame: sorry for posting it into parts, but this is what I get. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcus weird, can you print aapl['Adj Close'].keys()?

Comment: @YCFlame:  <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-03, ..., 2015-09-18]
Length: 934, Freq: None, Timezone: None

Comment: @Marcus It seems you can't get data before 2012-01-03 from yahoo, maybe there is no data at all before this date. I think you can just set the start_date to 2012-01-03, since you can't get the data before that.

Comment: @YCFlame I have changed it to a date in 2013 but nothing again - the same error.

Comment: @Marcus I think may be your time range is too long and fail to get all those data back from yahoo. You can try splitting your time range into several shorter range(like 3 days) and validate my solution

Comment: @Marcus And I edited my solution again to avoid a type error.

Comment: @YCFlame, do not bother any more. It again gives no result (although I shortened the period) 2013-01-03
nan
C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py:588: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
  warnings.warn(msg, RankWarning)
C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py:588: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
  warnings.warn(msg, RankWarning)

Comment: @Marcus this error happens after you using my latest solution?

Comment: @YCFlame, yes after applying the latest edit of your code.

Comment: @Marcus you can just post the last two lines of traceback here so I can check

Comment: @Marcus and since there is a line `tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]`, I think it may be a misunderstanding to use it to calculate daily data(In my opinion, this hurst function is used to calculate data for a time range rather than a day)

Comment: @YCFlame, you may be right, I have to accomodate the function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a `dataframe` to a function which expects a `list`

```
print( hurst( aapl['Adj Close'].values ) )
```