# Hurst Exponent code with new pandas datareader

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Fairly new to coding and have been browsing this site for a while, not clued up enough to give anything back yet though.

I'm trying to calculate the Hurst exponent using this code originally from QuantStart but modified to import data from Yahoo. [Daily Hurst Exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506130/daily-hurst-exponent)

**When running in Powershell I return these errors**: 
     C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py:35: FutureWarning:
The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package (pandas-datareader) and will be removed from pandas in a future
 version.
After installing the pandas-datareader package (https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader), you can change the import
`from pandas.io import data, wb` to `from pandas_datareader import data, wb`.
  FutureWarning)

**When changing from pandas.io import data, wb to from pandas_datareader import data, wb:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hurst.py", line 23, in 
    aapl = DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", datetime(2012,1,1), datetime(2015,9,18))
NameError: name 'DataReader' is not defined

Please can someone help and guide me in what changes I'm missing to get the script to run properly.

Thanks,
James

Comment: This seems like two questions in one. Please clarify a bit what code produces which error message. Short hint: when things are undefined, chances are that you need to import / include the libraries.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.
The only thing I change from the original code is switching "from pandas.io import data, wb to from pandas_datareader import data"

Which then causes "NameError: name 'DataReader' is not defined"

I think you could be right that I need to import/include more libraries.

Comment: try using data.DataReader(...) with your import

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
...
ts1 = DataReader(symbol, "yahoo", start_date, end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the usage in the [documentation](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance)
 for pandas datareader:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)

end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)

f = data.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)
```